# Selenium error: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have Chromium on my computer that runs Debian 9. Here's `scraper.py`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://python.org")
```

The Chromium binary is at the specified location. When I run python `scraper.py`, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/home/me/ENV/pbc_vss/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/me/ENV/pbc_vss/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: chromedriver != the chrome (or chromium) browser. have you downloaded the file located at the provided sites.google link?

Comment: What do I need to change for this to open in Chromium?

Comment: did you check that you have downloaded the file located at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home?

Comment: Where do I put the file “chromedriver?”

Comment: do you still get this error after installing your chromedriver executable?

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question it's hard to pick just one.

Comment: Put `chromedriver` in the same folder as chromium binary. Works now

Comment: great! glad to be of help

Answer (score 3):

specify the path where your chrome driver is located, download page https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/driver/chromedriver')
```

Comment: i suspect this is not a path issue so much as @Username just didn't have the necessary file, given their comments

Answer (score 1):

Your browser binary (in this case, for [chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium)) is not the same thing as your [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). Just having the binary means you can launch chromium yourself, for example, but webdrivers will not be able to launch their own instances of chrom(e/ium), thus preventing you from using selenium with them. The solution to this is to download a chromedriver executable of your choice (note that version may be significant) in a folder on your path, or directly supply the path when creating your webdriver.